# Word VBA Macro to switch ribbon tab on open

Tags: vba, tabs, ms-word, ribbon

I have a vba macro that runs from a ribbon button and opens a template. Modifications to the template are made using other buttons alongside the first. However, when the template opens from the "Template" tab as a new document, the "Home" tab is reselected. Is there code I can add to the end of the macro which would automatically switch it to the "Template" tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate with keyboard combination Alt + Home + (2x) Esc

```
SendKeys "%(H)", False
SendKeys "{esc}", True
SendKeys "{esc}", True
```

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, but for some reason I couldn't get it to work. Let's say I press F10 in Word, that brings up some tab letter shortcuts. Developer is letter "L". So, If I press F10, then L, I jump to the Developer tab. How can I do this using SendKeys (if possible)?